# How to get category name from product id in shopping cart?

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart

I want to get category name, which are products already added in shopping cart. But I want category name in shopping cart add action. Means **/checkout/cart/add** in addAction.

Thanks in addvanced.

Answer (score 4):

Product do have more than one category. Do you assume, that your product is only added to one category? Then you can just:

```
$ids = $product->getCategoryIds()
$category->load($ids[0]);
$category->getName();
```

better is to collect all category ids, then load a collection and take the categories from there.

## Performance (maybe)

What else you can do is add a field to the quote_item, implement an observer and add the category name to the quote item. Then you can just `$quoteItem->getCategoryName()`. But I'm not sure whether you have the category while adding a product to the cart. If not, you need to get it somehow :-)

Comment: I have fetch already those product's category using this type of code. But I want those product's category name, which product is already in shopping cart.

Comment: @PrashantParekh, this makes no sense. The product can be added to cart not through category (search, whishlist, reorder).

Answer (score 4):

$_item['product_id'] is a product id . We will find out the categoryid associated with the product.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item['product_id']);
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
```

Now we have category ID(s). One product can associate with more then one category, this is Magento default nature.

```
 foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($category_id);
        echo $_cat->getName();             
    }
```

$_cat->getName(); is your product category name. This is beneficial if product is associate with a single category. If a product is associated with multiple category then we need category ID to get product category name.

Comment: How to get current product category id and cart products category id, if both are different trigger Observer, could you pls help me with my post https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/284557/57334 @Asheem Patro

Answer (score 1):

You can get category id by using product id at any where 
1)first get product id and load catalog/product collection by this product id like

```
<?php  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid );?>
```

In that $productid is your product id variable ;

```
<?php  $product->getCategoryIds(); 
echo ($cats[0]); ?>
```

or

```
foreach($cats as $categoryId) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    echo $category->getName();  
}
```