# How to get product category ID on product compare page?

Tags: magento-1.7, php

I want to separate attributes according to product category id on product compare page.
means on ../catalog/product/compare/list.phtml

anyone can help me?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/11754/146. It's not exactly the same question, but it's close.

Comment: thanks for reply.
but not helpful in my case.

Comment: @tim http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/781557/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId());
$ids = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$categoryId = (isset($ids[0]) ? $ids[0] : null);
```

I know that loading a product in a loop may lead to performance issues but how many products can you have in a comparison list? I think it's safe to say, not that many.

Comment: `$_item` is already a product instance, so `$ids = $_item->getCategoryIds()` should work as well. If not, add the missing fields/joins to the collection.